# If a group has 14 men and 11 women, how many different teams can be made with $6$ people that contains exactly $4$ women?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> A group has $14$ men and $11$ women.
>   (a) How many different teams can be made with $7$ people?
>   (b) How many different teams can be made with $6$ people that contains exactly $4$ women?

Answer key to a is $257$ but I can't figure out how to get $257$? There's no answer key to b though, but here's my attempt:

$$\binom{25}{6} - \left[\binom{14}{6} + \binom{14}{5}  + \binom{14}{4} + \binom{14}{3} + \binom{14}{1} + \binom{11}{6} + \binom{11}{5}\right]$$

What I'm trying to do here is subtracting all men, all women, 5 men, 4 men, 3 men, 1 men, and 5 women team from all possible combination of team.

Thanks

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: Are you sure the answer key to (a) is not `\binom {25} 7` i.e. $\binom {25} 7$?

Comment: Ya that's what confuses me. It's just 257 and another similar problem has a similar small number when my answer is something bigger such as this. Maybe typos? Otherwise, it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

For the first one, number of ways you can choose $k$ woman and $m$ men= $11\choose k$+ $14\choose m$, such that $k+m=7$.

For the second one, number ways you can choose $4$ women= $14\choose4$

**AND** number of choosing $2$ men= $11 \choose 2$, when you have an **AND**, you gotta multiply them.

Comment: For the second, you swapped the number of men and women.